# trigger a modal on blade (laravel 4.2) depending if conditional statement is satisfied

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, bootstrap-modal

i have this blade that adds a user in the database and i wanted to use bootstrap modal to inform the user that the record has been added. This adding functionality works and my only problem is that i dont know how to display the modal here is my current code:

```
 @if ($errors->any())
    <ul>
        {{ implode('', $errors->all('<p style="color:red" class="error">:message</p>')) }}
    </ul>
    @else
    <li style="color:red">Record Added!</li> <!-- display modal instead li tag --!>
```

```
 @endif
```

and here is the code for the modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With blade conditionals any HTML within the block is valid, this means we can use `<script>` tags and add some inline javascript to trigger the modal. Assuming you have bootstrap-js and jquery the following should work for your scenario:

```
@if
..

@else
   <script>
       $('#modalid').modal('show');
   </script>    
@endif
```